# Is it efficient to build a list with a generator function

Tags: python, generator

When reading the book 'Effective Python' by Brett Slatkin I noticed that the author suggested that sometimes building a list using a generator function and calling list on the resulting iterator could lead to cleaner, more readable code.

So an example:

```
num_list = range(100)

def num_squared_iterator(nums):
    for i in nums:
        yield i**2

def get_num_squared_list(nums):
    l = []
    for i in nums:
        l.append(i**2)
    return l
```

Where a user could call

```
l = list(num_squared_iterator(num_list))
```

or

```
l = get_num_squared_list(nums)
```

and get the same result.

The suggestion was that the generator function has less noise because it is shorter and does not have the extra code for creating the list and appending values to it.

(NOTE clearly for these simple examples a list comprehension or generator expression would be better, but let us take it as given that this is a simplification of a pattern that can be used for more complex code that would not be clear in a list comprehension)

My question is this, is there a cost to wrapping the generator in a list? Would it be equivalent in performance to the list building function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing this I decided to do a quick test and wrote and ran the following code:

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time

TEST_DATA = range(100)


def timeit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time()
        print(f'running time for {func.__name__}  = {end-start}')
    return wrapped

def num_squared_iterator(nums):
    for i in nums:
        yield i**2

@timeit
def get_num_squared_list(nums):
    l = []
    for i in nums:
        l.append(i**2)
    return l

@timeit
def get_num_squared_list_from_iterator(nums):
    return list(num_squared_iterator(nums))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_num_squared_list(TEST_DATA)
    get_num_squared_list_from_iterator(TEST_DATA)
```

I ran the test code many times and each times (much to my surprise) the get_num_squared_list_from_iterator function actually ran (fractionally) faster than the get_num_squared_list function.

Here are results for my first few runs:

1.
running time for get_num_squared_list  = 5.2928924560546875e-05

running time for get_num_squared_list_from_iterator  = 5.0067901611328125e-05

2.
running time for get_num_squared_list  = 5.3882598876953125e-05

running time for get_num_squared_list_from_iterator  = 4.982948303222656e-05

3.
running time for get_num_squared_list  = 5.1975250244140625e-05

running time for get_num_squared_list_from_iterator  = 4.76837158203125e-05

I am guessing that this is due to the expense of doing a list.append in each iteration of the loop in the get_num_squared_list function.

I find this interesting because not only is the code clear and elegant it seems more performant.

Comment: cpython's 'list` is basically an array, so calling `append` will trigger (re-)allocations. Haven't looked into what `list(iterable)` does under the hood, yet.

Comment: I wouldn't trust such tiny tests, especially not when measured with `time.time`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann hmmm I'm not sure that the case is definitively proven - but I did try again with range(10000). I also tried running the functions in a different order in case the interpreter warming up could somehow effect the run time. And then ran it another dozen or so times and EVERY time the generator function ran faster, in every test. So I feel pretty confident that the result is good. (at least on my machine with this version of Python (3.6) ... etc.)

Comment: @SamRedway you really should be using the `timeit` module instead of rolling your own...

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that your generator with `list` example is faster:

```
In [4]: def num_squared_iterator(nums):
   ...:     for i in nums:
   ...:         yield i**2
   ...:
   ...: def get_num_squared_list(nums):
   ...:     l = []
   ...:     for i in nums:
   ...:         l.append(i**2)
   ...:     return l
   ...:

In [5]: %timeit list(num_squared_iterator(nums))
320 µs ± 4.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit get_num_squared_list(nums)
370 µs ± 25.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: nums = range(100000)

In [8]: %timeit list(num_squared_iterator(nums))
33.2 ms ± 461 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [9]: %timeit get_num_squared_list(nums)
36.3 ms ± 375 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

However, there is more to the story. Conventional wisdom is that generators are slower than iterating over other types of iterables, there's a lot of overhead to generators. However, using `list` is pushing the list-building code down into the C-level, so you sort of are seeing a middle ground. Note, using a for-loop can be optimized thusly:

```
In [10]: def get_num_squared_list_microoptimized(nums):
    ...:     l = []
    ...:     append = l.append
    ...:     for i in nums:
    ...:         append(i**2)
    ...:     return l
    ...:

In [11]: %timeit list(num_squared_iterator(nums))
33.4 ms ± 427 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit get_num_squared_list(nums)
36.5 ms ± 624 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [13]: %timeit get_num_squared_list_microoptimized(nums)
33.3 ms ± 487 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And now you see that a lot of the difference in the approaches can be ameliorated if you "inline" `l.append` (which is what the `list` constructor avoids). In general, method resolution is slow in Python. In tight loops, the above micro-optimization is well known and is sort of the first step one would take to make your for-loops more performant.

Comment: You took out the `**2`!

Comment: @user2357112 fixed. Yeah, that was a shocking difference in performance

Comment: So, what that mistake taught us is that most of the time is spent on squaring and we should thus *not* do that?

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes, I do my best to avoid doing anything at all, generally.

Comment: This is an interesting piece and the optimized loop was definitely faster than the non optimized loop - buuuut in all my tests I still found the generator function faster ... (Mac OS Python 3.6)